# How can I fix Xcode's open quickly?

Tags: xcode, xcode10.1

I wonder if I'm doing something to make it not work, but simply put after tapping `cmmd + shift + O` or going to `File >> Open quickly` the option doesn't show up. It's like I did nothing.

Wondering if this is a known Xcode bug or if I'm doing something.

I'm using Xcode `10.1`

Comment: Do you have an external monitor connected?

Comment: @Alladinian Yes. I have 2 monitors connected

Comment: That was it. I had playground opened in another window and once I opened that window. Xcode was showing the open quickly there. Can you put that into an answer?

Comment: Done. Glad that helped you, I had the same confusing experience a _lot_ of times :P

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You probably have more than one monitor connected.

This is something that confused me a lot of times as well; the quick search prompt will remember its position (you can drag it around) even on secondary monitors.

For what is worth, in my opinion, that field should always be presented on the current (in focus) editor.

Comment: never knew that I could drag it around. FWIW I never had this issue before. I've been using multiple monitors for 2 years now. The only change now is Xcode 10 & Macbook 2018